# Symfony Querybuilder left join merge arrays

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am currently facing a problem using the query builder and a left join. What I want to achieve is select all columns from the Article-Entity and, using a left join with two conditions, "append" a field to that array. In the snippet you'll see the working query without a join and the query with the left join and their results.

I know you can use "getScalarResult", but that produces the result shown in the snippet as well - it prefixes all columns from table "Article". What I would want is that result without the "a_" prefixes.

I know you can list the table fields in the select statement, but I do not want that query to be static but rather have it dynamic for when the table structure *might* change.

```
// default query
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.publishedAt IS NOT NULL')
            ->andWhere('a.publishedAt <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')
            ->andWhere('a.status = 2')
            ->orderBy('a.publishedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
// default result
array:5 [
  0 => Article {#723 
    -id: 18
    -title: "Title!"
    -slug: "slug"
    -content: "content"
    -image: "img.jpg"
    -author: BackendUser {#817 ▶}
    -status: 2
    -publishedAt: DateTime @1536546264 {#720 ▶}
    -ratingPositive: 1
    -ratingNegative: 0
    -articleRatings: PersistentCollection {#816 ▶}
    #createdAt: DateTime @1539163998 {#715 ▶}
    #updatedAt: DateTime @1539180102 {#709 ▶}
  }
  ...
]



// Left-Join-Query:
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->andWhere('a.publishedAt IS NOT NULL')
            ->andWhere('a.publishedAt <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()')
            ->andWhere('a.status = 2')
            ->leftJoin('App\Entity\Article\ArticleRating', 'ar', 'WITH', 'ar.article = a.id AND ar.user = ' . $userId)            
            ->addSelect('ar.rating as userRating')
            ->orderBy('a.publishedAt', 'DESC')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

// Left Join Result
array:5 [
  0 => array:2 [
    0 => Article {#722 ▼
      -id: 18
      -title: "Title"
      -slug: "Slug"
      -content: "Content"
      -image: "image.jpg"
      -author: BackendUser {#817 ▶}
      -status: 2
      -publishedAt: DateTime @1536546264 {#689 ▶}
      -ratingPositive: 1
      -ratingNegative: 0
      -articleRatings: PersistentCollection {#816 ▶}
      #createdAt: DateTime @1539163998 {#737 ▶}
      #updatedAt: DateTime @1539180102 {#732 ▶}
    }
    "userRating" => true
  ]
  ...
]



// getScalarResult - result
array:5 [▼
  0 => array:12 [▼
    "a_id" => 18
    "a_title" => "Title"
    "a_slug" => "slug"
    "a_content" => "content"
    "a_image" => "image.jpg"
    "a_status" => 2
    "a_publishedAt" => DateTime @1536546264 {#689 ▶}
    "a_ratingPositive" => 1
    "a_ratingNegative" => 0
    "a_createdAt" => DateTime @1539163998 {#737 ▶}
    "a_updatedAt" => DateTime @1539180102 {#732 ▶}
    "userRating" => "1"
  ]
  ...
]
```

My desired outcome would look like something like this:

```
array:5 [
    0 => Article {#722 ▼
      -id: 18
      -title: "Title"
      -slug: "Slug"
      -content: "Content"
      -image: "image.jpg"
      -author: BackendUser {#817 ▶}
      -status: 2
      -publishedAt: DateTime @1536546264 {#689 ▶}
      -ratingPositive: 1
      -ratingNegative: 0
      -articleRatings: PersistentCollection {#816 ▶}
      #createdAt: DateTime @1539163998 {#737 ▶}
      #updatedAt: DateTime @1539180102 {#732 ▶}
      -userRating- => true
    }
  ...
]
```

Comment: Your desired result is impossible, since Article has no field userRating

Comment: So I would have to merge the two arrays manually using PHP I guess?

Comment: The value of userRating exists inside articleRatings in any case, maybe you could get it from there.

Comment: That's why I'm using the left-join - I am getting the correct value, but I cannot get it inside the article object.